# Slide down animation by changing classes

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I have created a simple toast system. I have a non visible (`bottom: -50px; position: fixed;`) block:

```
<div class="toast" ng-class="$root.peekToast.class" ng-bind="$root.peekToast.msg"></div>
```

Then I add a `toast-show` (with animation) class using `ng-class` when toast is needed:

```
.ew-toast-show {
  -webkit-animation: ew-toast-show 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation: ew-toast-show 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ew-toast-show {
  100% { bottom: 20px; }
}

@keyframes ew-toast-show {
  100% { bottom: 20px; }
}
```

However, when the toast is ready to be closed, I want to have a class `toast-hide` that `slides-down` the toast when it replaces the `toast-show` class.

I have tried to duplicate the `show` animation logic by just using `-50px` instead of `20px`. It didn't quite work. It hid and showed the block before sliding it down.

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to change your code a bit, and you can support it, I think using `transform` and `transition` will be easier than `@keyframes`.

```js
$('#b').click(() => $('.toast').toggleClass('ew-toast-show'));
```

```css
.toast {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -50px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.ew-toast-show {
  transform: translateY(-70px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toast">Toast</div>
<button id="b">Toggle</button>
```

I added jQuery for convenience. The key is setting `transition` on `.toast`. In this example, we're saying that we want to animate the `transform` property and have it last for 0.5 seconds. Then, the class for when you show the toast uses `transform` to indicate the final position. CSS will take care of animating.